# Google colab: Setting GCP project for BigQuery magic using an environment variable

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-colaboratory

In colab, if I try to execute a simple bigquery query without explicitly providing the project-id like this:

```
%%bigquery
SELECT 1 AS test
```

then I get the following error:

```
OSError: Project was not passed and could not be determined from the environment.
```

I realise I can mitigate this error by specifying the `--project` parameter in the `%%bq` magic:

```
%%bigquery --project my-project-id
SELECT 1 AS test
```

but the text of this error suggest that perhaps it's possible to specify the project-id **by setting an environment variable** instead. Is this possible?

I'd prefer to be able to set up the env var at the top of the notebook then not specify the project id each time. I tried a guess of `GCP_PROJECT` and googled around the issue but to no avail. I couldn't turn up any docs or answers as to which env var I can set for the projectid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `GCLOUD_PROJECT` like this:

```
%env GCLOUD_PROJECT=your_project_id
```

Or, if you want to type a bit longer

```
%env GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT=your_project_id
```

I didn't find any document either. So, I dug up the code and found it [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python/blob/master/google/auth/environment_vars.py)